# Inspecting binary over sockets

Tags: sockets, websocket, binary, ascii, wireshark

I'm using WireShark to inspect data sent/received over a web-socket, however, all I see is nonsense.

`0000   1c 74 0d 7d 42 24 d8 5d e2 26 c1 7d 08 00 45 00  .t.}B$.].&.}..E.
0010   00 3c 75 4e 40 00 80 06 22 eb c0 a8 01 c0 4f 89  .<uN@...".....O.
0020   50 91 c4 f1 0f 78 72 e5 d0 f4 ea 5e 6e e2 50 18  P....xr....^n.P.
0030   00 40 91 b3 00 00 c2 8e 6d 06 87 95 7f 76 78 62  .@......m....vxb
0040   92 f9 54 2a 92 f9 b4 95 6c 06                    ..T*....l.`

I've seen this type of output before. The left is a line of binary, and the right is the decoded string (ASCII), right?

Is this data obfuscated/encrypted?

Is it possible to get cogent information from my socket?

Also, what do the [FIN] and [MASKED] flags mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and paste the data you supplied into a text file and append a line beginning with `0050` with nothing following it, you can then run `text2pcap -a infile.txt outfile.pcap` to convert the data to a pcap file that Wireshark can read and decode for you.

See the [`text2pcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html) man page for more information about this tool.

I have done this and the packet appears to just be a simple TCP segment.  There is no [FIN] or [MASKED] flag, only PSH and ACK.  For information about these TCP flags, refer to [RFC 793, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1), as well as the other RFC's mentioned at the top, which update this one.